# Custom gutenberg block fields are empty after refresh the edit page

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I created a custom Gutenberg block which was working fine till wp 6.3.2 .

But after updating to 6.4.2 , it is not working.

when i am entering data it is showing the data and post is also updated. But on front end there is no data.

When I refresh the post edit page then also fields are empty.

Ref: I created the block to store and show products from different marketplace.

I set an attribute "products" for the row. and created a form to enter new product row.

here is my js code:

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n; // Import __() from wp.i18n
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks; // Import registerBlockType() from wp.blocks
const { InspectorControls, useBlockProps } = wp.blockEditor;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const { TextControl } = wp.components;
/**
 * Register: custom products Gutenberg Block.
 *
 */
registerBlockType('wp-market/wp-market-products', {
    apiVersion: 2,
    title: __('Manual Products'),
    icon: 'shield',
    attributes: {
        products: {
            type: 'array',
            default: []
        }
    },

    /**
     * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the editor.
     * This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
     *
     */
    edit: function (props) {
        const { products, newProduct } = props.attributes;
        var blockProps = useBlockProps();

        // to create edit element
        function createEditEl() {
            let data = [];

            // Heading
            data.push(React.createElement(
                "h6",
                null,
                "Manual Products"
            ));

            // entered product
            data.push(React.createElement(
                "div",
                { class: 'product-rows-gutenberg' },
                createGutenbergManualProductRows()
            ));

            // new product
            data.push(React.createElement(
                "div",
                { class: 'new-manual-product-gutenberg' },
                createGutenbergManualProductNew()
            ));

            return data;
        }

        // function  for product rows
        function createGutenbergManualProductRows() {
            let data = [React.createElement("h6", { class: "sub-heading" }, ["Added products"])]
            // rows
            if (products && products.length > 0) {
                products.map((product, index) => {
                    data.push(React.createElement(
                        "div",
                        { className: 'manual-product-row-wrapper' },
                        formatProductRow(product, index)
                    ));
                });
            } else {
                data.push(React.createElement(
                    "div",
                    { className: 'manual-product-row-wrapper no-product' },
                    "No product added"
                ));
            }

            return data;
        }

        // to create product row
        function formatProductRow(product, index) {
            let data = [];

            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    { 
                        className: 'column column-id'
                    },
                    [
                        product.id ? product.id : '',
                        // edit field
                        createEditField('id',blockProps.id, index, product.id)
                    ]

                )
            );

            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'column column-title' },
                    product.title ? product.title : '',
                    // edit field
                    createEditField('title',blockProps.id, index, product.title)
                )
            );

            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'column column-price' },
                    product.price ? product.price : '',
                    // edit field
                    createEditField('price',blockProps.id, index, product.price)
                )
            );

            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'column column-link' },
                    product.link ? product.link : '',
                    // edit field
                    createEditField('link',blockProps.id, index, product.link)
                )
            );

            if (product.image) {
                data.push(
                    React.createElement(
                        'div',
                        { className: 'column column-image' },
                        [
                            React.createElement(
                                'img',
                                {
                                    src: product.image
                                }
                            ),
                            // edit field
                            createImageEdit(blockProps.id, index)
                        ]
                    )
                );
            } else {
                data.push(
                    React.createElement(
                        'div',
                        { className: 'column column-image no-img' },
                        // edit field
                        createImageEdit(blockProps.id, index)
                    )
                );
            }

            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'column column-store' },
                    product.store ? product.store : '',
                    // edit field
                    createEditField('store',blockProps.id, index, product.store, true)
                )
            );

            //button to delete the row
            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    'button',
                    { className: '', onClick: function () { products.splice(index, 1); props.setAttributes({ products: products.slice() }); } },
                    '-'
                )
            );

            return data;
        }

        // refresh the image preview
        function refreshGutenbergManualUploadImage(src) {
            let imgEl = document.querySelector('#' + blockProps.id + 'new-image-preview');
            let textEl = document.querySelector('#' + blockProps.id + 'new-image-text');

            if (src.length) {

                imgEl.src = src;
                textEl.classList.add('hidden');
                imgEl.classList.remove('hidden');
            }
            else {
                imgEl.src = '';
                textEl.classList.remove('hidden');
                imgEl.classList.add('hidden');
            }
        }

        // create store options
        function createStoreOptions(value = '') {
            let data = [];
            if (wp_market_block_stores) {
                wp_market_block_stores.map(store => {
                    data.push(
                        React.createElement(
                            'option',
                            {
                                value: store.slug
                            },
                            store.name
                        )
                    );
                })
            }
            return data;
        }

        // editing image
        function createImageEdit(blockId, index){
            return React.createElement(
                'span',
                {
                    className: 'column-edit-button dashicons dashicons-edit',
                    onClick: function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var image_frame;
                        if (image_frame) {
                            image_frame.open();
                        }
                        // Define image_frame as wp.media object
                        image_frame = wp.media({
                            title: 'Select Media',
                            multiple: false,
                            library: {
                                type: 'image',
                            }
                        });

                        image_frame.on('close', function () {
                            // On close, get selections and save to the hidden input
                            // plus other AJAX stuff to refresh the image preview
                            var selection = image_frame.state().get('selection');                           
                            var gallery_srcs = new Array();
                            var gallery_ids = new Array();
                            var my_index = 0;
                            selection.each(function (attachment) {
                                gallery_srcs[my_index] = attachment['attributes']['url'];
                                gallery_ids[my_index] = attachment['id'];
                                my_index++;
                            });
                            var srcs = gallery_srcs.join(",");
                            var ids = gallery_ids.join(",");

                            if(srcs){
                                products[index]['image'] = srcs;
                                props.setAttributes({ products: products.slice() });
                            }
                        });

                        image_frame.open();
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        // create edit field
        function createEditField(name, block_id, index, value, isStore = false) {
            return [
                React.createElement(
                    'span',
                    {
                        className: 'column-edit-button dashicons dashicons-edit',
                        onClick: () => showEditColumn(name, block_id, index, value)
                    }
                ),
                React.createElement(
                'div',
                {
                    className:'column-edit-field hidden',
                    id: 'edit-column-' + name + '_block-id_' + block_id + '_index_' + index
                },
                [
                    isStore ?
                    React.createElement(
                        'select',
                        {
                            className: 'edit-column-value'
                        },
                        createStoreOptions()                
                    )
                    :
                    React.createElement(
                        'input',
                        {
                            className: 'edit-column-value'
                        }                   
                    ),
                    React.createElement(
                        'button',
                        {
                            className: 'edit-column-save'
                        },
                        React.createElement(
                            'span',
                            {
                                className: 'dashicons dashicons-yes-alt',
                                onClick: () => saveEditColumn(name, block_id, index)
                            }
                        )
                    ),
                    React.createElement(
                        'button',
                        {
                            className: 'edit-column-cancel'
                        },
                        React.createElement(
                            'span',
                            {
                                className: 'dashicons dashicons-dismiss',
                                onClick: () => cancelEditColumn(name, block_id, index)
                            }
                        )
                    )
                ]
            )
            ]
        }

        // to show the edit field for a column
        function showEditColumn(name, blockId, index, value = '')  {
            let field = document.querySelector('#edit-column-' + name + '_block-id_' + blockId + '_index_' + index);
            if(field && field.classList.contains('hidden')) {
                field.classList.remove('hidden');
                field.querySelector('.edit-column-value').value = value;
            }
        }

        // to save the changes in edit field
        function saveEditColumn(name, blockId, index){
            let field = document.querySelector('#edit-column-' + name + '_block-id_' + blockId + '_index_' + index);
            if(field) {
                let newValue = field.querySelector('.edit-column-value').value;
                products[index][name] = newValue;
                field.classList.add('hidden');
                field.querySelector('.edit-column-value').value = '';
            }
            props.setAttributes({ products: products.slice() });
        }
        // to cancel the editing
        function cancelEditColumn(name, blockId, index){
            let field = document.querySelector('#edit-column-' + name + '_block-id_' + blockId + '_index_' + index);
            if(field) {
                field.classList.add('hidden');
                field.querySelector('.edit-column-value').value = '';
            }
        }

        // create new row
        function createGutenbergManualProductNew() {
            let data = [React.createElement("h6", { class: "sub-heading" }, ["Add new product"])]
            // id
            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    "label",
                    { for: blockProps.id + 'new-id', class: 'manual-product-label' },
                    [
                        React.createElement("span", null, "Product ID"),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input",
                            { type: "text", name: 'manual-product-id', id: blockProps.id + 'new-id' },
                        )
                    ]
                )
            );
            // title
            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    "label",
                    { for: blockProps.id + 'new-title', class: 'manual-product-label' },
                    [
                        React.createElement("span", null, "Title"),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input",
                            { type: "text", name: 'manual-product-title', id: blockProps.id + 'new-title' },
                        )
                    ]
                )
            );
            // price
            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    "label",
                    { for: blockProps.id + 'new-price', class: 'manual-product-label' },
                    [
                        React.createElement("span", null, "Price"),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input",
                            { type: "text", name: 'manual-product-price', id: blockProps.id + 'new-price' },
                        )
                    ]
                )
            );
            // link
            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    "label",
                    { for: blockProps.id + 'new-link', class: 'manual-product-label' },
                    [
                        React.createElement("span", null, "Link"),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input",
                            { type: "url", name: 'manual-product-link', id: blockProps.id + 'new-link' },
                        )
                    ]
                )
            );
            // image
            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    "label",
                    { for: blockProps.id + 'new-image', class: 'manual-product-label image-upload' },
                    [
                        React.createElement("span", null, "Image"),
                        React.createElement(
                            "div",
                            {
                                id: blockProps.id + 'new-image-text',
                                className: 'new-image-text'
                            },
                            'No Image'
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "img",
                            {
                                id: blockProps.id + 'new-image-preview',
                                className: 'hidden preview'
                            }
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input",
                            {
                                type: "button",
                                name: 'manual-product-image-upload',
                                id: blockProps.id + 'new-image-upload',
                                value: 'Select image',
                                onClick: function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    var image_frame;
                                    if (image_frame) {
                                        image_frame.open();
                                    }
                                    // Define image_frame as wp.media object
                                    image_frame = wp.media({
                                        title: 'Select Media',
                                        multiple: false,
                                        library: {
                                            type: 'image',
                                        }
                                    });

                                    image_frame.on('close', function () {
                                        // On close, get selections and save to the hidden input
                                        // plus other AJAX stuff to refresh the image preview
                                        var selection = image_frame.state().get('selection');
                                        var gallery_srcs = new Array();
                                        var gallery_ids = new Array();
                                        var my_index = 0;
                                        selection.each(function (attachment) {
                                            gallery_srcs[my_index] = attachment['attributes']['url'];
                                            gallery_ids[my_index] = attachment['id'];
                                            my_index++;
                                        });
                                        var srcs = gallery_srcs.join(",");
                                        var ids = gallery_ids.join(",");
                                        document.querySelector('#' + blockProps.id + 'new-image').value = srcs;
                                        refreshGutenbergManualUploadImage(srcs);
                                    });

                                    image_frame.open();
                                }
                            },
                        ),
                        React.createElement(
                            "input",
                            {
                                type: "hidden",
                                name: 'manual-product-image',
                                id: blockProps.id + 'new-image'
                            },
                        )
                    ]
                )
            );
            // store
            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    "label",
                    { for: blockProps.id + 'new-store', class: 'manual-product-label' },
                    [
                        React.createElement("span", null, "Store"),
                        React.createElement(
                            "select",
                            {
                                name: 'manual-product-store',
                                id: blockProps.id + 'new-store'
                            },
                            createStoreOptions()
                        )
                    ]
                )
            );
            // add button
            data.push(
                React.createElement(
                    'button',
                    {
                        className: 'add-manual-product', onClick: function () {
                            products.push(
                                {
                                    id: document.querySelector('#' + blockProps.id + 'new-id').value,
                                    title: document.querySelector('#' + blockProps.id + 'new-title').value,
                                    price: document.querySelector('#' + blockProps.id + 'new-price').value,
                                    link: document.querySelector('#' + blockProps.id + 'new-link').value,
                                    image: document.querySelector('#' + blockProps.id + 'new-image').value,
                                    store: document.querySelector('#' + blockProps.id + 'new-store').value,
                                }
                            );
                            props.setAttributes({ products: products.slice() });
                        }
                    },
                    '+'
                )
            );

            return data;
        }

        let returnEL = createEditEl();
        return React.createElement('div', blockProps, returnEL);
    },
});
```

I entered the product details and added to the row and it was showing in the row. I click on update post, products were still showed in the row.

But when I am refreshing the post edit page the products is empty.
It should show the products which I have added.